# Effects on Earths development if 95% of the water was missing?

Tags: science-based, biology, society, earth-like, water-bodies

If a planet just like Earth formed but with 95% less water than on our world, what effect would this have on the development of the planet – in outline. Things to consider, might we still see plate tectonics, a stable biosphere and ultimately civilization?

Comment: Well, for starters, the fiddly bits around Norway probably wont get made.

Comment: Nooo! surely not ;o)

Comment: That sounds an awful lot like Mars....  Maybe worse.

Comment: Don't forget that most of Earth's water is not in the ocean but [in the mantle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_distribution_on_Earth#Water_in_Earth.27s_mantle) (estimations vary between 60% and 90% of the total amount of water). Not to mention that an awful lot of water is bound as [water of cristallization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_of_crystallization).

Comment: I'm not sure if life could have formed if Earth only had 5% it's current water. And if it did, I can't see it making out of the single cellular stage.

Comment: I think this is far too broad. Stick with one thing at a time, plate tectonics, will life evolve, etc.

Comment: @kingledion I had considered asking a lot of separate questions but thought I would stick to just the one as I am only asking for answers in outline.

Answer (score 4):

This change would have **very** large effects on Earth, starting with formation and continuing through the present day. Let's start with the [obligatory XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/53/) and work from there; this is a map of the current Earth with about 95% of the water gone.

[image: from https://what-if.xkcd.com/53/]

### Formation

It's currently estimated that 90+% of all the water on Earth [has been here since the planet formed](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/10/141030-starstruck-earth-water-origin-vesta-science/). This raises an interesting question about *how* exactly this hypothetical planet might have happened, but I'll handwave that for now.

### Plate tectonics

Without water, it's unlikely that plate tectonics as we know them would happen at all. Water serves as a kind of lubricant between plates and enables rapid cooling near hydrothermal vents. Without water, we might be looking at a Mars-style single plate crust or Venus' [rapid overturning mantle](https://www.nature.com/articles/ngeo2941?WT.feed_name=subjects_solid-earth-sciences) without the dynamic system we're used to.

### Biology

Biology, as a whole, is unlikely. As far as we know, life requires water and without the massive amounts of it, it'd be much harder to create life. Admittedly, we aren't sure exactly how life formed, but [all of our working hypotheses](https://futurism.com/abiogenesis-7-scientific-theories-origin-life-one-new-one/) either start in the ocean or a "primordial soup" (okay, except the "aliens did it" one). Water makes chemical reactions possible as a solvent, is the electron donor for photosynthesis, and has a [whole long list](http://www.rsc.org/Education/Teachers/Resources/cfb/water.htm) of things that make it nice to have around. Even [these scientists](https://www.earth-syst-dynam.net/2/37/2011/esd-2-37-2011.html), who argue that life is an unavoidable consequence of Earth's environment, lean heavily on water to do the heavy lifting.

### Other things to consider

I can't imagine there would be many clouds, and the ice caps would be proportionally smaller. The planet would be much colder, due to the greenhouse effect of water molecules in the atmosphere, and the temperature variation would be much higher without the oceans to regulate temperature.

Comment: looks like plenty of overlap here, both typing at the same time. :)

Comment: @TimB indeed! Glad to see another brain going the same direction as mine

Comment: You're showing the 3Km map and claiming that's 95% of the water drained.  XKCD doesn't make that claim (at least not that I saw).  I'm guessing, but based on XKCD's assertion that the oceans are eventually disconnected, I'm pretty sure even the "drained" map inadequately shows what the world would be like with only 5% of its water extant.

Comment: @JBH I hadn't intended it as a truly useful bit of information, just some context. If the ocean levels were to drop 3km, a back of the envelope calculation suggested that there'd be about 10% of the water left (average ocean depth is ~3.8km. Of course, neither I nor Randall wanted to deal with ice in ice caps or groundwater, so I figured it was a vague estimate at best.

Answer (score 4):

Let's break this question down into several sections.

**Life**

Life would be a LOT harder to form without water. The problem isn't energy per se, it's radiation. The complex amino chains needed to form life are actually harder to assemble into unicellular life under water but they are destroyed almost instantly in a primordial Earth being bombarded by solar radiation.

Additionally, the early Earth's atmosphere was almost completely devoid of O2. Billions of years worth of early plant life changed that by releasing excess O2 as a waste gas. That in turn gets converted to Ozone (O3) by that same radiation, resulting in the ozone layer that (ironically) protects us above water from a lot of that same radiation. So, without much water, life would probably still form, but there would be distinct limits on how much life could form, and the idea of land based animals would be almost unreachable.

Aside from radiation, there is also the fact that most life needs the movement of water (in the form of tides) to change the environment in a regular pattern in order to hide, hunt, lay eggs, etc. It is generally accepted that the moon plays an important part in the survive-ability of Earth, and that even the planetary body collision that created the moon in the first place (and changed the tilt of Earth) had a lot to do with creating ideal conditions (including seasons). While the Moon is out of scope of this discussion, its effect on the oceans in the form of tides is not.

**Climate**

Assuming some other form of life found Earth, its climate would be much harsher. The massive amount of water that we have on Earth acts as a thermal mass that regulates and moderates our surface temperatures. This is (in part) why weather always seems more temperate on the coast than it does inland. An arid planet would have much hotter days, colder nights (like deserts today) but the good news (if you can call it that) is that there'd be no tropical storms.

Storms are driven by a range of factors, but the biggest is the Coriolis effect caused by temperature variations driven by surface sunlight and water. Cyclones also tend to build up mass by sucking up water over the ocean, generating significant angular momentum which dissipates slowly when the eye of the cyclone comes over land. If there's no significant water bodies to help generate this effect, storms can be expected to be relatively dry, and therefore more gentle. That said, the winds over desert conditions would generate a significant amount of static electricity, so one could expect gentler storms with a lot more lightning. It's a trade-off I guess.

**Plate Tectonics**

This one is a bit of a grey area for me and not in my general field of expertise. That said, if I was to guess, plates would generally be more stable, not less. The reason I think that is because water puts a massive strain on the planet underneath and I would assume that this (in part at least) causes a lot of the stress that causes the Earth's surface to move over time. Internal pressures from the spinning core would also be an issue, but that is just as likely to generate more volcanoes with less downward pressure counteracting it. That in turn MIGHT lead to more greenhouse gases in the atmosphere, but this is speculation.

**Stable Rotation**

Finally, it should be noted that the surface of the Earth is not perfectly round. This makes a measure of sense because otherwise we wouldn't have continents that sit above sea level. That said, water very neatly evens out those variations meaning that for the purposes of planetary orbits and rotations the planet is close enough to being a sphere that its orbit and rotation is stable *enough*.

Actually, this isn't strictly true. The Moon also plays a big part in this and the rotation of the Earth causes the water to pull out more at the equator, causing an elliptical effect. If the Earth was tidally locked, you'd actually see most of Europe, Russia and Canada disappear and massive land masses rise at the equator, but again I digress.

The point being, the stable rotation of the Earth is a big deal life wise, and can't be as accurately predicted without water smoothing out the bumps, so to speak.

So, all in all, the Earth without as much water as it has would be a pretty desolate place and is unlikely to have an oxygen rich atmosphere, Ozone layer, or even temperate climate. With a smaller zone for habitability (smaller, single ocean, probably in the Pacific Basin) evolution would have a hard time keeping up with our levels of development and therefore intelligent life, let alone society, is unlikely.